# Pixel size of text on server side before writing it on page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, svg, d3.js

I want to calculate text with maximum pixel size beforehand and then allocate the maximum width size to all other texts. getBBox gives me below error:

```
TypeError: Object [ TEXT ] has no method 'getBBox'
```

and getComputedTextLength() also does not work.

Both these methods give pixel size after it is written to page. I am creating chart on server side i.e. nodejs and I want to calculate pixel size before writing it to page. Is there any method for this?

Edit:
Adding code

```
    chart.selectAll("svg:text")
    .data(d3Data)
    .enter().append("svg:text")
    .attr("class", "d3LegendText")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        textLength = d.seriesName.length*6;
        if (prev_legend_x + textLength + legend_padding_x > width) {
            legend_y = legend_y + 15;
            legend_x = 7;
        } else {
            legend_x = prev_legend_x;
        }
        prev_legend_x = legend_x + textLength + legend_padding_x;
        return "translate(" + legend_x + "," + legend_y + ")"; })
    .text(function(d, i) {
        console.log(this.getBBox().width);
            return d.seriesName;
    })
```

You can ingnore variables in transform. I have written it to calculate pixel size depending on number of characters in text. But I want exact width of text.

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Hi, I have added part of code in which I want width.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nL9gkb04/

Comment: I am using it on nodejs server and get about error :(

Comment: You can't use this with node as the output needs to be rendered to get the dimensions.

Comment: is there any other function to get pixel size on nodejs server?

Comment: You need to render it to do that. You may be able to do it with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: why would you want to do that on the server?